# How to get my program to log the user into Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, authentication

i have been working on a program that will enter usernames and passwords if someone plugs in a Usb, but i don't know how to enter a windows log in password. So the idea is to have my program running so it can find if the usb is plugged in if so it will use keybd_event to enter the password and to hit enter. how would i get my program to run so i can do this?

Answer (score 8):

You need to write a [GINA DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380543.aspx) (XP) or a [Credential Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) (Vista / Seven)